# jQuery plug in question

Tags: jquery-plugins

I'm using following script to mark current page with a.active on the URL.

```
$(function () {
        var menus = $('#menu >li > a');
        menus.removeClass('active');

        var matches = menus.filter(function () {
            return document.location.href.indexOf(this.href) >= 0; 
        });

        matches.addClass('active');
    });
```

I have following website: [website](http://www.thepuremassage.co.uk/index.html)

As we can it does work on all menu items exept 'massage treatments' - why??

Any help much appreciated. Pete

Comment: These pages are .html, theres no point to use javascript you can simply just add class='active' manually to it

Comment: Is it being executed after the page has completed loading?

Comment: Point is that if I added it manualy - and edit ONE more subpage I would have to edit all 12 pages(4 categories + 8 subcategories) to change the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>`  is missing on the 'massage treatments' page

Comment: Thanks! Is always the small things!